# Discord Bot for Stock Price Alerts

Tags: api, discord

I'm on a project to create a stock price alerting tool for our team. I get the current price for a certain stock from an API. I was wondering if it's possible for a Discord bot to accept user inputs for a stock that you want to have an alert on e.g. $TSLA 1850, then the bots sends them a DM when the stock reaches that price.

I don't anything about coding discord bots yet, please bear with me. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can save the these values in a dictionary that is to be saved into a file. Using the stock name as a the key and having another dict storing userid's to the price that needs to be attained. Then have a looping function that checks the stock price of every stock in the larger dict and seeing if it beats the price in the nested dict. If it does than do a call like user = bot.get_user(user_id) and user.send("YOUR MESSAGE"). LMK if you want a full answer on this

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it can be done. I was trying to make sure it is possible before investing time learning to code Discord bots.

Comment: No problem :) LMK if you need anything